# how to use php code in html?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Its a childish question but i am not getting how to  fix it .I am using html code in php code . It work fine . but when i use php code in that html code it show error . my code is->

```
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"> <span class="page_no">Page 1 of 30</span> <ul class="pag_list">';
```

it work fine but i want to use php code in this in place of page 1 of 30. like this->

```
  $config['uri_segment'] =4;

 $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"> <span class="page_no">Page ."$config['uri_segment']". of 30</span> <ul class="pag_list">';
```

please help me out . Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @GolezTrol Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/first_project/application/controllers/admin/selectUser.php on line 30

Comment: If you're going to downvote, leave a comment. I think this is a legitimate question...

Comment: @PastorBones yes sir this is a legitimate question according to me also .

Answer (score 2):

The PHP code is in a string and is treated as such.

Change it to:

```
 $config['uri_segment'] = 4;

 $config['full_tag_open'] = 
    '<div class="pagination"> <span class="page_no">Page '.
    $config['uri_segment'].
    ' of 30</span> <ul class="pag_list">';
```

Note I put the line breaks in for clarity only. It's actually the closing (and re-opening) single quotes and the removal of the double quotes around `$config['uri_segment']` that do the trick. If you look at your code in a highlighter (even in your question here), you can see that it is red (like a string) and not highlighted (like PHP code).

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo...your `.` are out of place and on the wrong side of the `"`. It also looked like you were mixing your quotations `'/"`. Try this:

```
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"> <span class="page_no">Page ' . $config['uri_segment'] . ' of 30</span> <ul class="pag_list">';
```